# How to access Array created in closure?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I created scheduleDict1 and inserted it into scheduleArray1. I can only get the closure to "see" scheduleArray1 when it is declared in the closure as in the code now. However, I can't access scheduleArray1 anywhere other than the closure.

I have tried declaring the scheduleArray1 in the MainViewController class instead of the closure but it will not be seen inside the closure!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


class MainViewController: UITableViewController {

  //  var scheduleArray1 = [[String: String]]()
    var scheduleDict = [String: Any]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        retrieveSchedule()
        }

    func retrieveSchedule(){
        let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "squadrons/vt-9/2019-04-02/events/")
        ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            var scheduleArray1 = [[String: String]]()
            var count = 0
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() {
                let refToPost = Database.database().reference(withPath: "squadrons/vt-9/2019-04-02/events/" + "\(count)")
                refToPost.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            //      let data = snapshot.children
                    let scheduleDict1 = snapshot.value as! [String: String]
                    scheduleArray1.append(scheduleDict1)

                  //  self.print(scheduleArray1)
                })
                count += 1
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: You need to pass a closure to `retrieveSchedule` so that it can be invoked from your observe closure. It isn't just a question of variable scope, it is one of timing. The observer closure executes asynchronously.

Comment: I think don't have a problem in variable, The problem is as he said @Paulw11
try to use DispatchGroup  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup